# Shifting 4 bits using a single number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have to write a method that takes in an integer as a parameter (0, 1, 2, or 3). I have to use that to create a bitmask with a 0. So, if the parameter is 0, than the bitmask will be `FFF0`, for 1: `FF0F`, 2: `F0FF`, 3: `0FFF`. I am trying not to hardcode it.

What I have tried, but it only works partially:

```java
int bob = 0xFFFF;
int multi = 2;

multi = multi << param;
```

this works with 1 and 2, and for even those, it makes it `0xFF00`, and `0xF000`.

I am trying not to use multiplication either (that would make it a lot easier, so I don't want to use it).

Comment: Removing all mentions of "java" is probably not actually that good an idea... Made me not sure how it was going to handle negative numbers (e.g. manu-fatto's answer wouldn't work if `int` means a 16 bit number - since that would make `0xFFFF` equal to -1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
bitmask = 0xFFFF;
bitmaskmask = 0xF;
bitmaskmask = bitmaskmask << parameter * 4;
bitmask = bitmask ^ bitmaskmask;
```

Comment: thanks. I used a similar technique to avoid multiplication, using 2 if clauses. 

I used an int 2 as a base and depending ont he parameter I shifted it, b/c 2 is 0b10, and 2 << 1 is 0b100, which is 4, and 2 << 2 is 0b1000, which is 8 and so on. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

```
0xFFFF - (0xF << (param * 4))
```

Comment: Or `0xFFFF - (0xF << (param << 2))` if you really want to avoid multiplication...

Comment: 0xFFFF - (0xF << (param << (1 << 1))) :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your inputs, you can achieve what you are looking for using the bitwise XOR operation as follows:

```
xorMask = 0x000F << (4*multi) ;
result = bob ^ xorMask ;
```

This creates an XOR mask with 1 bits in the appropriate portion of the 16 bit value, then XORing it with the input to 0 those bits in the output.

Comment: Except... if `multi == 2 && bob == 1` you wind up with `0x0F01` instead of `0x0001`.